# how to handle NaN value in mathjs.evaluate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongodb-query, mathjs

```
console.log(mathjs.evaluate("(goodCount/(goodCount+reject_count))>0.99", {
  goodCount: 0,
  reject_count: 0,
  Total_Planned_time: 10
}))
```

my problem is that if goodCount & reject_count zero this function return NaN but I want Either true or false by function
so can you suggest how to write condition if NaN value came it return true.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi there. If you found my answer helpful, please accept it. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```js
(async () => {
  const mathjs = await import("https://cdn.skypack.dev/pin/mathjs@v7.1.0-lgPTcYfuwGwbFfYrv7Km/min/mathjs.js");

  function evaluateExpression() {
    const result = mathjs.evaluate("goodCount / (goodCount + reject_count)", {
      goodCount: 0,
      reject_count: 0,
      Total_Planned_time: 10,
    });

    if (isNaN(result)) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
    console.log(evaluateExpression());
  });
})();
```

```html
<button>Evaluate the expression</button>
```

Comment: "(goodCount/(goodCount+reject_count))>0.99" con you please write condition in this string so mathjs.evaluate give me return value true

Comment: I'm actually not familiar with MathJS. Let me check the documentation.

Comment: Oh, and why are you using an external library instead of just writing it as a JavaScript expression (i.e. `goodCount / (goodCount + reject_count) > 0.99`)?

Comment: @lakshitsingh you can output the function that Julia has written to the console.log with `console.log(evaluateExpression());` trying to write it into your string might be more difficult.

Comment: I also can't reproduce your issue. When I try the code you included in your original post, [it returns `false`](https://jsfiddle.net/gtjzf6cn/).

Comment: @MikeW    ..... I have issued my condition store in the database in a string form so if mathjs.evaluate give true or false according to match condition my further value comes. but if Nan value come I am got getting a response so I want Condition in string

Comment: @Julia "(goodCount/(goodCount+reject_count))<0.99" in both case it return false so none of my condition satified so i want if NaN come it will true above condition

Comment: I don't see where you are getting a `NaN` value?

Comment: @Julia   mathjs.evaluate("(goodCount/(goodCount+reject_count))", {
    goodCount: 0,
    reject_count: 0,
    Total_Planned_time: 10,
  });    try this 0/0 give me NaN

Comment: Agreed it's a little odd as I get false too when running on their site - even running `(0/0)>0.99` in the console gives a false even when `(0/0)` gives NaN... strange, could it be something to do with the environment you're running the evaluation in?

Answer (score 0):

Just been trying to solve a similar problem, here's how I used it to solve yours...

```
math.evaluate("r = (goodCount / (goodCount + reject_count)); isNaN(r) ? true : r > 0.99", {
  goodCount: 0,
  reject_count: 0,
  Total_Planned_time: 10
}).entries[0];
```

This returns `true` when `goodCount` and `reject_count` are both zero.